# How to load controller in template file in Opencart 2.3x version

Tags: php, templates, controller, runtime-error, opencart2.3

I have use opencart 2.3x version for create new theme...
I want to load controller in template file (.tpl).

```
 <?php
     $load = $this->registry->get('load');
     $html = $load->controller('module/hit_sidebar',$data);
 ?>
```

But it will give error :

```
Notice: Undefined property: Template\PHP:registry
```

How can i solve this...?

Comment: did you get the solution of this issue? I am also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

> You can not use `registry` in template(.tpl) file in opencart 2.3x version.

it work only lower then opencart 2.2x version..